# App crash report origin

Tags: ios

Here is the Crash report can anyone help me identify whats actually going on.. If you need anything from me please let me know.. Thank you

```
Date/Time:       2011-06-07 20:00:50.156 -0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.3 (8J2)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x360c8a1c 0x360b7000 + 72220
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3619f3b4 0x3616c000 + 209844
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36197bf8 0x3616c000 + 179192
3   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00044a64 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34fd606c 0x34fd0000 + 24684
5   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00042e36 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 46
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00042e8a std::terminate() + 10
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00042f5a __cxa_throw + 78
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34fd4c84 0x34fd0000 + 19588
9   CoreFoundation                  0x314b948a 0x3141b000 + 648330
10  CoreFoundation                  0x314b94c4 0x3141b000 + 648388
11  UIKit                           0x31724a4c 0x3151b000 + 2136652
12  UIKit                           0x31725e02 0x3151b000 + 2141698
13  UIKit                           0x315504c6 0x3151b000 + 218310
14  UIKit                           0x3154ab02 0x3151b000 + 195330
15  UIKit                           0x3151f7d0 0x3151b000 + 18384
16  UIKit                           0x3151f20e 0x3151b000 + 16910
17  UIKit                           0x3151ec4c 0x3151b000 + 15436
18  GraphicsServices                0x30da2e70 0x30d9e000 + 20080
19  CoreFoundation                  0x31490a90 0x3141b000 + 481936
20  CoreFoundation                  0x31492838 0x3141b000 + 489528
21  CoreFoundation                  0x31493606 0x3141b000 + 493062
22  CoreFoundation                  0x31423ebc 0x3141b000 + 36540
23  CoreFoundation                  0x31423dc4 0x3141b000 + 36292
24  UIKit                           0x31549d42 0x3151b000 + 191810
25  UIKit                           0x31547800 0x3151b000 + 182272
26  Womp Womp App                   0x0000216a 0x1000 + 4458
27  Womp Womp App                   0x00002134 0x1000 + 4404

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x360c93ec 0x360b7000 + 74732
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x361a06d8 0x3616c000 + 214744
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x361a0bbc 0x3616c000 + 215996

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x360c9fbc 0x360b7000 + 77756
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x35d9a032 0x35d94000 + 24626
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x35d9b03a 0x35d94000 + 28730
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x35d9a5ea 0x35d94000 + 26090
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x361a058a 0x3616c000 + 214410
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x361a0bbc 0x3616c000 + 215996

Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x360c6c00 0x360b7000 + 64512
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x360c6758 0x360b7000 + 63320
2   CoreFoundation                  0x314912b8 0x3141b000 + 484024
3   CoreFoundation                  0x31493562 0x3141b000 + 492898
4   CoreFoundation                  0x31423ebc 0x3141b000 + 36540
5   CoreFoundation                  0x31423dc4 0x3141b000 + 36292
6   WebCore                         0x36a8c27e 0x36a86000 + 25214
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3619f30a 0x3616c000 + 209674
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x361a0bb4 0x3616c000 + 215988

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x3f86748c    r5: 0x00000006      r6: 0x00182aac      r7: 0x2fdfe030
    r8: 0x3ed10964    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x0017dff0     r11: 0x00000001
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdfe024      lr: 0x3619f3bb      pc: 0x360c8a1c
  cpsr: 0x00000010
```

Comment: If you have a core dump, best load it into the debugger and start tracing assembly. Good luck!

Comment: Im not sure what that is? Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode open **Organizer** window and go to **Devices** tab and Select **Device Logs** under **Library section**. Import the crash log if its not present in **Organizer** window and clock on the **Re-Symbolicate** icon at the bottom. You can see some changes in the crash log file. Then check the lines representing your app name(Womp Womp App). The hex-values in the right will be replaced with something like `0x0000216a +[MyCrashedClass myCrashedMethod:] (MyCrashedClass.m:<lineNumber>)`.

Check the line number in the crashed class, and that will be the crashed point in your app.